# Chrome native image lazy loading works inside iframe only

Tags: html, image, google-chrome, iframe, lazy-loading

Chrome 81, FF 75 (latest for today)

in Chrome native image lazy loading works inside iframe only. why? in FF works good

***page1.htm***(lazy loading does not work in Chrome but works good in FF):

```
<p style="margin-bottom: 1000px;">Please scroll down. The image is below the viewport.</p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 1000px;">Please scroll down. The image is below the viewport.</p>
<img src="https://wallpaperplay.com/walls/full/5/e/a/218959.jpg" loading="lazy">
```

***page2.htm***(lazy loading via iframe works both in Chrome and in FF):

```
<iframe src="page1.htm">
```

is it Chrome's bug? in FF it works good

(you can check image deferred loading via scrolling and Developers tools -> Network)

Comment: edit your question. you can use  snippet tools and add better than code. read this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I haven't used code snippet as it is run inside iframe which could mislead readers because my question/issue is iframe-dependant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the same issue but **only** when the image is close *enough* to the viewport. Otherwise it is being loaded lazily.

Please try to open this minimal working example in Chrome and slowly scroll the page down. The image will be loaded when the viewport is approximately in the middle of the page.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .dummy {
                height: 700vh;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="dummy"></div>
        <img src="https://yasminfinch.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Hello-icon-300x212.jpg" loading="lazy">
    </body>
</html>
```

Without confidence, I can suggest it is a feature, not a bug. Some kind of optimization. It reduces the chance to see the image is loading when, for example, user scrolls up/down quickly enough.

Comment: thank you! really it works in case of increasing height of elements before image. Firefox works a bit different(with loading="laze"), it loads image exactly when you scroll to image

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to explicitly set `width` attribute either inline or in CSS file.

In  fact, you can try the [original demo](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/img-loading-lazy). Lazy loading on Chrome will not work if you remove the width and height attributes in this demo.